# Existe alguna forma de darle un radio al borde de un TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, estilos

He intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
textbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

Pero eso funciona con Windows Forms y no me parece buena idea fucionar WPF y Window Forms.

Tambien trate de hacerlo asi:

```
    <Border Name="border1">
        <TextBox Name="Box1"/>
    </Border>
```

pero no me funciona tampoco, le da el radio pero aparece de la siguente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero que el Textbox tenga el estilo, no que algo ande a su alrededor con la forma que deseo.

No supe como solo mostrar la primera pantalla.

NECESITO PODER HACERLO POR CODIGO C# PREFERIBLEMENTE.

Comment: Intentaste con la propiedad [CornerRadius](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: @Einer CornerRadius no es una propiedad del Textbox, segun he investigado y he probado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLO con código C# es muy complejo lograr lo que necesitas, ya que requiere modificar la `Template` del `TextBox` para agregar funcionalidades que NO tiene. Yo lo hice de este modo:

**Primero:**
Necesitarás crear un `UserControl`, podrías modificar el `TextBox` directamente, pero de la manera en que te lo presento podrás reutilizar el control tantas veces como quieras, yo llamé al control "ModTextBox" pero puedes darle el nombre que quieras.

Crea un nuevo UserControl y en el etiquetado XAML debes poner esto:

```
<TextBox x:Class="TuProyecto.UserControls.ModTextBox"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="23" d:DesignWidth="120" Margin="0" >
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Height" Value="23"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Label FontFamily="{Binding PlaceHolderFontFamily}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Visibility="{Binding PlaceHolderVisibility}" FontSize="{Binding PlaceHolderFontSize, TargetNullValue=12, FallbackValue=12}" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding PlaceHolderText, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue=''}" x:Name="PART_PlaceHolderLabel" Focusable="false" Margin="0" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" Padding="2,0,5,0"  />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="TextBox.IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="TextBox.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Luego en el código del UserControl colocas esto:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TuProyecto.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para ModTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ModTextBox : TextBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Propiedades
            
            [Category("ModTextBox")]
            public FontFamily PlaceHolderFontFamily
            {
                get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(PlaceHolderFontFamilyProperty); }
                set { SetValue(PlaceHolderFontFamilyProperty, value); }
            }
            
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderFontFamily.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderFontFamilyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderFontFamily", typeof(FontFamily), typeof(ModTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Segoe UI")));
            
            
            
            [Category("ModTextBox")]
            public string PlaceHolderText
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderTextProperty); }
                set { SetValue(PlaceHolderTextProperty, value); }
            }
            
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderText", typeof(string), typeof(ModTextBox), new PropertyMetadata("Texto"));
            
            private static Brush DefaultPlaceHolderForeground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF8D8D8D"));
            
            [Category("ModTextBox")]
            public Brush PlaceHolderForeground
            {
                get { return (Brush)GetValue(PlaceHolderForegroundProperty); }
                set { SetValue(PlaceHolderForegroundProperty, value); }
            }
            
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderForeground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderForegroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ModTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(DefaultPlaceHolderForeground));
            
            
            [Category("ModTextBox")]
            public double PlaceHolderFontSize
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(PlaceHolderFontSizeProperty); }
                set { SetValue(PlaceHolderFontSizeProperty, value); }
            }
            
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderFontSize.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderFontSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(ModTextBox), new PropertyMetadata((double)12));
            
            
            [Category("ModTextBox")]
            public Visibility PlaceHolderVisibility
            {
                get { return (Visibility)GetValue(PlaceHolderVisibilityProperty); }
                set { SetValue(PlaceHolderVisibilityProperty, value); }
            }
            
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(ModTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
            
            
        #endregion
        
        public ModTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ModTextBox);
            TextChanged += ModTextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        
        void ModTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Text.Length > 0)
            {
                PlaceHolderVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                PlaceHolderVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        
        #region Implementación de INotifyPropertyChanged
            //Lo uso para la propiedad RemainText así no queda como DependencyProperty
            //pero mantiene la notificación de cambios a la UI
            protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Segundo:**
Ahora que lo tienes, lo declaras en la ventana donde lo quieras usar, en este caso en el MainWindow:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TuProyecto.UserControls"        
mc:Ignorable="d"  
x:Class="TuProyecto.MainWindow"        
Title="Tu Proyecto">
    <Grid>
        <controls:ModTextBox  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="200" PlaceHolderText="Nombre de usuario"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Y eso es todo, un `TextBox` con borde curvo y con `placeholder`, aunque eso último es un extra, puedes ignorarlo si quieres.

[image: textbox con borde curvo]

Bye.